# How to fix `self` escapes the method body here?

Tags: rust

We want to pass to `thread::spawn` data, which it forces to have `'static` lifetime, which causes error

```
borrowed data escapes outside of method [E0521]
`self` escapes the method body here

Note: requirement occurs because of the type `EventLoopGroupSchedulerWorkerThreadData<'_>`, which makes the generic argument `'_` invariant

Note: the struct `EventLoopGroupSchedulerWorkerThreadData<'event_loop_group_scheduler>` is invariant over the parameter `'event_loop_group_scheduler`

Help: see <https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/subtyping.html>; for more information about variance
```

---

We know for sure that data which we pass to `thread::spawn` will have same lifetime as `'event_loop_group_scheduler`, because `Drop` implementation of `EventLoopGroupScheduler` continuously unparks potentially sleeping(while waiting for tasks to appear) event loop threads until all of them reach point in code in event loop which checks if we have no tasks and `Drop` was called, and break event loop and finish execution

Stable Rust doesn't let us pass data to `thread::spawn` without `'static` requirement or `scope`(which blocks current thread until child thread finish execution, which we want to avoid), but we don't want to have such a strict requirement, especially since such strict requirement usually propagates

---

Here is a reproducible example

```rust
struct EventLoopGroupScheduler<'event_loop_group_scheduler> {
    thread_count: usize,
    worker_thread_data_arc:
        Arc<EventLoopGroupSchedulerWorkerThreadData<'event_loop_group_scheduler>>,
    // We have `worker_thread_data_ptr` to optimize access to data in `worker_thread_data_arc`
    // in hot paths
    worker_thread_data_ptr:
        *const EventLoopGroupSchedulerWorkerThreadData<'event_loop_group_scheduler>,
}

struct EventLoopGroupSchedulerWorkerThreadData<'event_loop_group_scheduler> {
    // Some properties
    // ...
    action_queue_list: Vec<Mutex<VecDeque<Box<dyn FnOnce() + Send + 'event_loop_group_scheduler>>>>,
    // Some properties
    // ...
}

impl<'event_loop_group_scheduler> EventLoopGroupScheduler<'event_loop_group_scheduler> {
    pub fn new(
        max_possible_concurrent_thread_count: usize,
        thread_count: usize,
        os_timer_precision: Duration,
    ) -> Self {
        let worker_thread_data_arc = Arc::new(EventLoopGroupSchedulerWorkerThreadData {
            // Some properties
            // ...
            action_queue_list: (0..thread_count)
                .map(|_| Mutex::new(VecDeque::new()))
                .collect(),
            // Some properties
            // ...
        });
        let worker_thread_data_ptr = Arc::into_raw(worker_thread_data_arc.clone());
        let event_loop_group_scheduler = Self {
            thread_count,
            worker_thread_data_arc,
            worker_thread_data_ptr,
        };

        event_loop_group_scheduler.start_event_loop_group();

        event_loop_group_scheduler
    }

    fn start_event_loop_group(&self) {
        for thread_index in 0..self.thread_count {
            let worker_thread_data_arc_clone = self.worker_thread_data_arc.clone();

            let _join_handle = thread::spawn(move || {
                // This line causes error:
                //
                // borrowed data escapes outside of method [E0521]
                //
                // `self` escapes the method body here
                //
                // Note: requirement occurs because of the type `EventLoopGroupSchedulerWorkerThreadData<'_>`, which makes the generic argument `'_` invariant
                //
                // Note: the struct `EventLoopGroupSchedulerWorkerThreadData<'event_loop_group_scheduler>` is invariant over the parameter `'event_loop_group_scheduler`
                //
                // Help: see <https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/subtyping.html>; for more information about variance
                let worker_thread_data = worker_thread_data_arc_clone.as_ref();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can never use `thread::spawn` with borrowed data, and your use of a lifetime for your `dyn FnOnce`s means that they're *allowed* to contain borrowed data.

Your choices are:

- Don't allow borrowed data; remove the lifetime parameters and change the lifetime on the `dyn FnOnce` to `'static`. This is probably what you will need to do.
- Use [scoped threads](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/thread/fn.scope.html). The scope function blocks on all threads terminating, so they can safely use borrowed data. However, this means you can't have a “start” operation that lets the threads run in the background.